# How to compile javadoc from sources in simplest way?

Tags: java, javadoc

Suppose I have project directory `MyProject`, under which I have `src` directory with sources of the program.

I want to compile all javadocs from there. What is the simplest command to issue?

If I run

```
javadoc -sourcepath ./src -d ./docs
```

I get an error

```
javadoc: error - No packages or classes specified.
```

Can't it deduce packages from source files?

**EDIT 1**

This way also causes an error

```
...MyProject>javadoc -sourcepath ./src *.java -d ./docs
Creating destination directory: "./docs\"
javadoc: error - File not found: "*.java"
1 error
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following worked for me

```
javadoc -sourcepath ./src -d ./docs -subpackages .
```

Answer (score 11):

The man page says it will only explicitly document packages that it is given. There is an option called subpackages that recursively documents the given package and all it subpackages, but you must still specify all base packages.

eg.

```
javadoc -d /home/html -sourcepath /home/src -subpackages java -exclude java.net:java.lang
```

http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/javadoc/

Comment: THe following worked: `javadoc -d ./docs -sourcepath ./src -subpackages org`

Answer (score 10):

In linux, it worked for me when I did the following

`javadoc -d docs/ $(find . -name *.java)`

I hope this helps

Comment: Worked for me! I had to add a . to the find command: `find . -name *.java`.

Comment: How about generating the javadocs within a project with multiple directories and packages not within the root path? My find command can find it, but I receive X number of errors depending on the number of X source files.

Answer (score 3):

try using `javadoc -sourcepath ./src *.java -d ./docs`

Comment: P.S. of course there are a lot of java files under `src` actually.

Comment: This won't include subpackages and `*.java` should be `**/*.java`.

Answer (score 3):

The lazy way is to use Eclipse : *Project --> GenerateJavadoc*  and choose the package/project you want to document.

Answer (score 0):

For me also the following worked:

```
javadoc -sourcepath ./src **/*.java -d ./docs
```